# Get last element in Collection

Tags: php, symfony, collections, doctrine, doctrine-collection

I'm trying to get a property on the last element in a collection. I tried

```
end($collection)->getProperty()
```

and

```
$collection->last()->getProperty()
```

none works

(tells me I'm trying to use `getProperty()` on a boolean).

```
/**
 * Get legs
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getLegs()
{
    return $this->aLegs;
}

public function getLastlegdate()
{
    $legs = $this->aLegs;

    return $legs->last()->getStartDate();
}
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: Are you sure `$collection` has items in it? `end()` will return `false` on an empty array.

Comment: Please provide some code to help us understand better assist you

Comment: `$collection->last();`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem you have is due because the collection is empty.
Internally the `last()` method use the `end()` php function that [from the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

> Returns the value of the last element or FALSE for empty array.

So change your code as follow:

```
$property = null

if (!$collection->isEmpty())
{
$property =  $collection->last()->getProperty();
}
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This `$collection->last()->getProperty()` is breaking the law of Demeter. The function should have a single responsibility. Try this.

```
/**
 * @return Leg|null
 */
public function getLastLeg(): ?Leg
{
   $lastLeg = null;
   if (!$this->aLegs->isEmpty()) {
     $lastLeg = $this->aLegs->last();
   }
   return $lastLeg;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime|null
 */
 public function getLastLegDate(): ?\DateTime
 {
   $lastLegDate = null;
   $lastLeg = $this->getLastLeg();
   if ($lastLeg instanceOf Leg) {
     $lastLeg->getStartDate();
   }

   return $lastLegDate;
 }
```